# How to extract a certain part of a string in R using regular expressions

Tags: r, regex

How to convert the following string in R :

```
this_isastring_12(=32)
```

so that only the following is kept

```
isastring_12
```

Eg

```
f('this_isastring_12(=32)') returns 'isastring_12'
```

This should work on other strings with a similar structure, but different characters

Another example with a different string of similar structure

```
f('something_here_3(=1)') returns 'here_3'
```

Comment: What is the logic of conversion ? Keep everything after....? Or remove everything after.. ?Or something else ?

Comment: @RonakShah to keep the part highlighted

Comment: so `sub(".*(isastring_12).*", "\\1", "this_isastring_12(=32)")` would work ?

Comment: yes but it wouldn't generalise, I guess if the parens were `(.*?)` it might work?

Comment: that is what I mean when I asked you for the logic of conversion ? Do you want to keep everything after first underscore till an opening bracket is found or is there some other logic involved ?

Comment: @RonakShah eg `another_string_4(=1)` would fail with it

Comment: @RonakShah I've added an additional example, I hope it's more clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sub` to extract everything from first underscore to opening round bracket in the text.

```
sub(".*?_(.*)\\(.*", "\\1", x)
#[1] "isastring_12" "here_3"       "string_4"
```

where `x` is

```
x <- c("this_isastring_12(=32)", "something_here_3(=1)", "another_string_4(=1)")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the package *unglue*.

Borrowing Ronak's data :

```
x <- c("this_isastring_12(=32)", "something_here_3(=1)", "another_string_4(=1)")
library(unglue)
unglue_vec(x, "{=.*?}_{res}({=.*?})")
#> [1] "isastring_12" "here_3"       "string_4"
```

- `{=.*?}` matches anything until what's next is matched, but doesn't extract anything because there's no lhs to the equality
- `{res}`, where the name `res` could be replaced by anything, matches anything, and extracts it
- outside of curly braces, no need to escape characters
- `unglue_vec()` returns an atomic vector of the matches